# Protractor | Linux Machine | WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Protractor and newbie to it I have installed protractor using 
npm i -g protractor
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start

when I run protractor conf_master.js
I am getting following error

```
[chrome #01-1] [20:01:12] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[chrome #01-1] [20:01:16] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.289.122.156:21199/wd/hub
[chrome #01-1]
[chrome #01-1] /data/home/aflsexchange/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546
[chrome #01-1]         throw new ctor(message);
[chrome #01-1]               ^
[chrome #01-1] WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir
[chrome #01-1] Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
[chrome #01-1] System info: host: '<myurl>', ip: '10.247.189.139', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
[chrome #01-1] Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[chrome #01-1] remote stacktrace: #0 0x55f67c8507e9 <unknown>
[chrome #01-1]
```

I am using Linux machine. Please let me know about the solution

Comment: Check if you have enough space on your disk

Comment: I have 3.2GB available in my machine

Comment: Do you know where your temp dir has to be created? Can you get to that folder?

Comment: I am not sure where to create that temp dir

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to create a **temporary directory** while trying to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

This error can occur due to different configuration issues or incompatibility between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- **Node** is updated using the **Package Manager**.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user (preferably with root/admin priviledge).
- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v78.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 78.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: I am using a redhat machine on a server which doesnt have a GUI access. everything I can do is through a terminal/putty

Answer (score 0):

Usually this problem is related to the permissions please use custom **user-data-dir** below you will find small example solved problem for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=~/.config/google-chrome')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://www.google.com'
driver.get(url) 
get_url = driver.current_url 
print(get_url)
```